# How can I fiter a list using url parameters?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have an all items page and I would like the results to be filtered by a particular column dynamically using a url parameter?
I think I have done this before but I can't seem to recall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=MyField&FilterValue1=XYZ
```

Comment: Hello Charles. Sorry I am dense today. If the column was lastname and the value was Smith how does that work with the above parameters, I tried a few ways obviously I need more sleep. lol

Comment: Hi, no worries. You need field internal name, if you renamed Title field it would be FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=Brown, if you are using a standard Contacts list it will be LastName (no space), if you created a Last Name field it would be Last_x0020_Name. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Charles. Any idea why I am getting  "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."? :(

Correlation ID:77c5f919-fd60-45ba-b2f7-ff4289e81e3b

Comment: I think it is because you don't use Field Internal Name. Go to list settings, click on Last Name field (as if you are modifying field type etc) and look at the last part of the URL. You will see the internal name for the field. Perhaps it was first created as something else and renamed to Last Name ?

Comment: Glad it is sorted.